# Why Google app engine throwing persistence exception

Tags: java, google-app-engine, web-applications

I am writing a web application using java on the Google app engine. Everything was working ok cause I had deployed and run the application numerous times. After I updated my jdk 7 to update 6 (had a lower version of jdk 7) and deployed it I started getting a 500 Http response code (internal server error). When I check the logs a:

```
 Uncaught exception from servlet
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Provider error. Provider: org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jpa.DatastorePersistenceProvider 
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createFactory(Persistence.java:176)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:112)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:66)
```

I am using the jpa datanucleus version 1 because I need support for the jersey framework which was giving some incompatibility issues. I don't know what is causing this problem cause I haven't changed anything in my code since the last deployment that worked. Help please!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was cause by the update I made to the jdk. I downgraded it to jdk 6,changed the project compiler version to 1.6, recompiled, deployed and that fixed the problem.